# Prove $f(y)=\inf \{||y-x||:x \in S\}$ is convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convex-optimization

Let $S$ be a nonempty convex set in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and  $f:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows:

$f(y)=\inf \{||y-x||:x \in S\}$.Prove that $f$ is convex.

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407374/is-the-minimum-of-a-parametric-convex-function-convex-again