# Show that $-\left(\min_{w\in C}(w^\top s+\frac12\|w\|_2^2)\right)$ is convex or show that it is concave

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

$$f(s)=-\left(\min_{w\in C}(w^\top s+\frac12\|w\|_2^2)\right)$$ where $C$ is a compact and convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

I believe that the function is concave, but I need to show that it is convex (which could be false). Please give me any result. I am thinking of using this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407374/is-the-minimum-of-a-parametric-convex-function-convex-again) which answers that the minimum of a parametric convex function is convex to prove that it is concave.

Comment: Do you want to prove that the optimization problem is convex? Or else?

Comment: @the_candyman, I believe that the function is concave, but I need to show that it is convex (which could be false). Please give me any result. I am thinking of using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407374/is-the-minimum-of-a-parametric-convex-function-convex-again to prove it as concave.

Comment: The minimum of linear functions is concave, and the negative of a concave function is convex.

Comment: @p.s. Sorry, I think I do not completely understand your statement, the minimum function includes two terms.

Comment: I guess, to be more precise, it's an affine function of $s$ (though it's common to call affine functions linear).

Comment: @p.s. Could you give a proof, thank you.

Comment: Here's a proof for the maximum of convex functions being convex. Minimum of concave is similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373229/show-that-the-maximum-of-a-set-of-convex-functions-is-again-convex

Comment: @p.s. So your conclusion is that $f(s)$ is convex? Could you see the answer below, is it correct? It says my $f(s)$ is concave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given any family of convex functions, the pointwise supremum is convex. See the answer here: [Prove the supremum of the set of affine functions is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287619)

(It assumes that the domain is compact, but the proof does not use this, and in any case one can always assume the domain is compact by restricting to a line segment.)

Multiplying by $-1$, we obtain that the pointwise infimum of concave functions is concave.

---

Affine functions are concave, hence so is the infimum in the definition of $f(s)$, so that $f(s)$ is convex. This argument does not require that $C$ is convex.

---

Note: it is not automatic that the minimum in your question exists (this can fail for certain $C$ if the term $\frac12 \lVert w \rVert^2$ is not there). But you can write it as
$$f(s) = \frac12 \lVert s \rVert^2 - \inf_{w \in C} \frac12 \lVert s + w \rVert^2 $$

and this infimum is attained because $C$ is closed. Moreover, we see that
$$f(s) = \frac12 \lVert s \rVert^2 - \frac12 d(s, -C)^2 \,.$$

Comment: Hi thank you for the solution, there is one question, so you are saying my $f(s)$ is concave, is that a typo? By adding a negative sign there does that mean the function is convex.

Comment: I think there's a sign error here. The conclusion should be f is convex. For example, when $C=R^n$, $f(s)=\frac{1}{2}\|s\|^2$ which is clearly convex.

Comment: @p.s. Does that mean any family (even the variable is not based on $s$) is also true that the infimum that family of concave functions is concave?

Comment: @7337dtd Yes, the infimum of a family of concave functions is concave.