# Is the minization of a strictly convex function still strictly convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Given a strictly convex function $f(x,y)$, is the following function still strictly convex?

$$ g(x) := \inf_y f(x,y) $$

Is there any counterexample for it?

---

There is a question here [Is the minimum of a parametric convex function convex again?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407374/is-the-minimum-of-a-parametric-convex-function-convex-again)
But the question is for the convex case, does this hold for the strictly convex case?

Comment: some vocab might help: $g$ is sometimes called a "marginal function" of $f$. I know that marginalization preserves quasiconvexity, lower semicontinuity, and convexity. However, I am not sure for strict convexity!

Comment: Under the additional assumption that the infimum is attained (i.e. $g(x, y) = \min_y f(x, y)$ one can show that $g$ is strictly convex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As demonstrated in the other answers, $g$ need not be strictly convex. However, under the additional assumption that the infimum is attained, i.e. $g(x) = \min_y f(x, y)$ for all $x$, one can show that $g$ is strictly convex:

Let $x_1, x_2$ be distinct points in the domain of $g$ and $0 < \lambda < 1$. Choose $y_1, y_2$ such that $g(x_1) = f(x_1, y_1)$ and $g(x_2) = f(x_2, y_2)$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
 g(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2)  &= \inf_y f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2, y)\\
&\le f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2), \lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2) \\
&\boxed{<} \lambda f(x_1, y_1) + (1-\lambda)f(x_2, y_2) \\
&= \lambda g(x_1) + (1-\lambda)g(x_2) \, .
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and it really helps!

Answer (score 6):

The function $f \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ given by
$$
f(x,y) = \exp(y) + \exp(x+y)
$$
is a counterexample, since $g(x) = 0$.

Comment: I was just about to post $f(x, y) = e^{x^2+y}$ as a counterexample. Yours is even simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
f(x,y)=e^{x^2-y}\,.
$$
The gradient and Hessian of this function are
$$
\nabla f=\begin{pmatrix}2x\\-1 \end{pmatrix}e^{x^2-y}\,,\quad\nabla^2f=\begin{pmatrix}2+4x^2&-2x\\-2x&1\end{pmatrix}e^{x^2-y}\,.
$$
Both eigenvalues of the Hessian are real and strictly greater zero.
The function $f$ is therefore strictly convex. However,
$$
g(x)=\inf_yf(x,y)\equiv 0
$$
is only convex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!